# InsydeH20 BIOS - Supervisor password set but not being asked

Tags: bios, passwords

I've got an older Toshiba Satellite Pro L870-19E laptop. Years ago, I set a supervisor password in it's BIOS (which is still known to me). This was required to change certain settings.

Holding F2 on boot, I enter the BIOS. It does not ask any password (like it once did). I am immediately presented with the usual tabs and settings. Most of those settings cannot be selected/highlighted or changed. Makes sense, as I'm not logged in as supervisor.

Under the tab 'Security', I can see the BIOS password for 'User' is [Not Registered], while 'Supervisor' is [Registered]. I cannot touch the supervisor password. Setting a user password changes nothing I can see. The BIOS still doesn't ask any password on boot or when entering the BIOS menu.

I have tried flashing the latest (and only) BIOS version I could find on the official website. The tool (a Windows exe) refuses because my BIOS is already on it's version. It is likely I have upgraded my BIOS in the past while the supervisor password was already set. I can't really remember. Might that be the cause of this bug?

InsydeH20 Setup Utility Rev. 3.7

Comment: No idea really, but you could try clearing the password, rebooting, and resetting the password. Or even try "Restore Defaults" and set it again.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe I cannot edit the supervisor password, only the user password. I can't even highlight the option. Setup Defaults (F9) is displayed at the bottom of the menu along with the other hotkeys, but nothing happens when pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Covid-19, I have been unable to access the laptop for over a year. However I did get in touch with Toshiba support (Dynabook) and with their help, I was able to resolve this issue:

1. During boot, (not waking up from hibernation or similar) rapidly pressed the INS key.
2. Laptop asked for supervisor password. Entered it and pressed enter. (Only alternative was F11, which opened BIOS with limited options. F2 during or right after the dialogue seemed to have no effect.)
3. Laptop booted into Windows. From the Windows login screen, I rebooted the computer.
4. During reboot, rapidly pressed F2 to enter BIOS setup.
5. No more grayed out options in the BIOS! I was able to erase the supervisor password.

Dynabook also provided me with a plan B, which I did not try:

*"Remove AC-Power + Main Battery, short Jumper (JRST2001 near RTC battery ) continuously and plugin AC-Adapter + press Power button in parallel, wait for about 5-10 seconds."*
(The next bit I have translated from Dutch) *" 'Shorting' the jumper is difficult, and you probably will have repeat it a couple of times; maybe even slightly scratch it with a screwdriver or a similar tool, as there is often a coating on the jumpers."*

Another option for Toshiba laptops appears to be the SVPW(32) utility. I did not try this. https://support.dynabook.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=108503

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your BIOS is really messed up if, as per your comment, "Restore Defaults" does nothing (and doesn't even prompt you!)

At minimum you will likely have to follow the manufacturer guidelines to hardware resetting your BIOS. Likely removing the battery and CMOS battery will reset it.

If that doesn't fix it, your BIOS is corrupted/otherwise faulty, and your BIOS chip would need to be replaced.

Comment: I unplugged the power, removed both batteries and waited a couple of minutes. The first thing I got when I rebooted was a BIOS prompt: press F2 to set date and time. I was able to set them, once. (Not after reboorting again.) However, nothing else has changed. All settings were retained and I'm still unable to change them. There is still no way to reset to defaults in the BIOS (F9/exit tab). I guess I need to do more to force a BIOS reset. I can't find anything on that online, so I'll be contacting Toshiba support. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this thread it pointed me in the right direction for clearing a supervisor password on a Toshiba Satellite Pro C50-A-1E2. By the CMOS battery there is 3 sets of jumper pads. Scratch the 2 pads a bit underneath (NOT next to) JRST2001. With the AC adapter plugged in hold a flathead screwdriver to those pads underneath JRST2001, now press and hold the power button for 30 seconds. Thats it, power up, no more supervisor password.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).